# React dim element that is rendered from a map

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am working on showing images in a card using React. The images come from a API and are resolved when rendering the images page. Now I want to use the Dimmer component from the React Semantic-UI design library and dim an image on a mouseover. I tried the following example from the document page:

```
const dimmedID = this.state.dimmedID
const collections = this.state.collections
const collectionsList = collections.map((project) =>
  <Dimmer.Dimmable
    key = { project.id }
    as = {Image}
    dimmed = {dimmedID === project.id ? true : false}
    dimmer = {{ active, content }}
    onMouseEnter = {() => { this.handleShow(project.id) }}
    onMouseLeave = {() => { this.handleShow('') }}
    src = { project.thumbnail }
    />
)
```

When triggering the onMouseEnter, the dimmedID state object is set to the id of the image. However, all images that are rendered are being dimmed. Not the image which the mouse is on. I tried with a shorthand if-else on the dimmed parameter but that does not seem to work. When hovering with the mouse over one image, all images get dimmed.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently the fix is easy... so much for reading...

```
const dimmedID = this.state.dimmedID
const collections = this.state.collections
const collectionsList = collections.map((project) =>
  <Dimmer.Dimmable
    key = { project.id }
    as = {Image}
    dimmed = {dimmedID === project.id ? true : false}
    dimmer = {{ active: dimmedID === project.id, content }}
    onMouseEnter = {() => { this.handleShow(project.id) }}
    onMouseLeave = {() => { this.handleShow('') }}
    src = { project.thumbnail }
    />
)
```